# How to get Cyrillic responsetext

Tags: vb6, character-encoding, winhttprequest

```
Dim http As WinHttpRequest
Set http = New WinHttpRequest 
http.open "POST", "test.php", False
http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
http.send "txtmbx=test"
msgbox(http.responsetext)
```

`http.responsetext` is in Cyrillic and I'm unable to read text. How can I retrieve Cyrillic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [WinHTTPRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does not support an encoding method, and while it doesn't explicitly say, I expect it uses `CP_ACP`, the system default codepage when converting from the received byte data to a string.

You can use the [`ResponseBody`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384009%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method to get the data as a byte array and use [`StrConv`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263373.aspx) to convert to a string as you wish.

Comment: Thank for your response it lead me to the right direction. If i put my string in byte array and use responsebody and strConv, when i display message box still message is unreadable, but if i save in a text file for example  test.html with <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />, and run html, characters are just fine I use ADO Stream object to convert utf8 bytes to string. Thanks Again

Comment: Using ADO for this is extremely overkill. You should really use [MultiByteToWidechar()](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=33525)